# What is the support for the suggestion that reality is a computer simulation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, universe, theory-of-everything

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Quantum Physics really suggests this universe as a computer simulation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/759/does-quantum-physics-really-suggests-this-universe-as-a-computer-simulation)

I know the title sounds far-fetched, but the idea was first brought to my attention by a comment by Prof. Jim Gates of the University of Maryland during the [2011 Issac Asimov Memorial Debate](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYeN66CSQhg).

Google lead me to [this essay](http://www.bottomlayer.com/bottom/argument/Argument4.html) which seems to argue that the universe/reality shares many analogues to how a modern Turing machine (a computer) does what we perceive it to do. It doesn't come out and state that *The Matrix* ought to be reclassified as a documentary, but it leaves that possibility open.

Not being a physicist, I'm wondering just how much water these ideas might hold. Is this an avenue that we really ought to explore or are these scientists abusing an (apparently uncanny) analogy?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/759/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic, the same question, no doubt. But are the answers to that question applicable to mine?

Comment: @Amazed: If you want, you can edit this question so that it(the actual question being asked) is distinct from the other one. Then someone will reopen it (you can speed it up by asking [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-coupling))